# Pop-out of hyper-v window when connected to host through terminal services?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-terminal-services, mstsc

I sometimes use Terminal Services to remote into my work machine.  Then, on my work machine, if I enter a Hyper-V window that's maximized, I can't figure out how to minimize the Hyper-V window to get back to my host machine.  It's quite annoying.

Anyone know an easy way to do this?

Note: I'm also using a macbook pro keyboard to TS into the host machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have already Googled it, but the answer is to hit ctrl+alt+pause. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/hyper-v-vm-connection-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx